# Track communication code in Apache Spark source code

Tags: apache-spark

Anyone knows how can I track down the segment of code that actually sends/receives bytes (be it code or data) over the network in Apache Spark?
I think its wasteful to do the debugging of Apache Spark source code when operating in local mode, since it never touches that part.

I'm still trying to get my head around the remote debugging of Spark job, which I'm hoping would allow me to step through the Spark source code.

Thanks

Comment: Howabout https://github.com/apache/spark/tree/3c0156899dc1ec1f7dfe6d7c8af47fa6dc7d00bf/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/network ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I already kind of have idea that communication is happening from this code portion. But it would be nice to step through the application to get to know exact function names instead of guessing.